# set the Minimum and Maximum value for X axis in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to set the Minimum and Maximum value range for the X axis like we do for Y axis using leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(..)

Answer (score 2):

For setting the x-values, simply create a new data object (e.g. `LineData`) and set your x-values for it:
(this example will create x-min: 0 and x-max: 30)

```
private void addEmptyData() {
   // create 30 x-vals
   String[] xVals = new String[30];

   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
       xVals[i] = "" + i;

   // create a chartdata object that contains only the x-axis labels (no entries or datasets)
   LineData data = new LineData(xVals);
   mChart.setData(data);
   mChart.invalidate();
}
```

This will create an empty chart with your desired bounds.

For dynamically adding entries, refer this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/DynamicalAddingActivity.java

Comment: Thank you Alok, if we need to create a continues horizontal sliding graph in aChartEngine, we use set the mix and max range for X axis and update it continuously. But by following the above method to do the same looks expensive, isn't it??

Comment: It might be. But we have only this option in MPAndroidChart.

Comment: I will accept it definitely after some time, but am looking for better method to achieve this. If I accept it now only, possibly we won't get the best method. Will accept it for sure :)